# cmd error: "'Code' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I opened cmd and entered this command

```
code .
```

, I got this error:

> 'Code' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What is the problem, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to do?
If you use Windows, you can open cmd (The command prompt) and type `code .`
This will open VSCode. 

If you want to run an Angular app, you should open the VSCode terminal, navigate to the root of the Angular app (the same folder where package.json is) and run `ng serve -o`.


If you want to create a new Angular app, run `ng new app-name`

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the directory containing your VS Code executable isn't in your system's `PATH` environment variable.

The installation procedure for VS Code [should do this by default for Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line), so I'm not sure why you're getting this error (unless that same cmd window was already open before you installed VS Code, in which case, you need to close and re-open it for its environment to pick up the updated `PATH` variable)

> Windows and Linux installations should add the VS Code binaries location to your system path. If this isn't the case, you can manually add the location to the Path environment variable.

The directory where VS Code is installed depends on whether you installed it as [a system installation, or a user installation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows).

- If you did a user installation, then the directory you need to add to the `PATH` is `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`. You should modify the user `PATH` and not the system `PATH` variable for this (found in the top half of the environment variable modification window)
- If you did a system installation, then the directory you need to add to the `PATH` is `C:\Program Files\Micorosoft VS Code\bin`. You should modify the system `PATH` and not the user `PATH` variable for this (found in the bottom half of the environment variable modification window)

To open the environment variable modification window, use the Windows search bar and search "Edit the system environment variables", and open the matching search result.